# What is the meaning of those two sections in a NSCollectionView

Tags: macos, xcode5

The picture below is of an NSCollectionView

Note the two segments, one vertical and the other horizontal. What are they?

[image: CollectionView]

Below is the context within the NIB.

[image]

Comment: I think they are the scrollers of the scrollbar.  Clicking about with the mouse should give some clues.

Comment: Clicking on them has same effect as if I would click the view itself. Someone please show me wrong.